# Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI not working well in all platforms

Tags: winrt-xaml

In my windows store app I used Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI class to capture Images and Videos. The recorded videos are working fine in Windows environment. But the same recorded file is not played well in Ipad.

I will include the code here

```
 CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
             dialog.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
             dialog.VideoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIVideoFormat.Mp4;
             dialog.VideoSettings.MaxResolution =    CameraCaptureUIMaxVideoResolution.LowDefinition;

             StorageFile capturedMedia = null;
             if( _showVideo )
                 capturedMedia = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.PhotoOrVideo);

             else
                 capturedMedia = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a bug report. Sometimes there are bugs.

This is something you should report at http://connect.microsoft.com than here.

Your contribution to Connect helps other developers.